# walking through executable

Tags: c++, debugging, executable

So I compile a program called test.cc creating test in the same folder. When I execute test by doing

```
./test
```

everything passes. However I am I want to follow how test goes through the code and what functions it hits, etc. How can I do this?

Comment: Use your debugger?

Comment: This depends on what system you are working on. What OS, IDE, and compiler, are you using?